# Export Quill editor content with superscript and subscript to excel

Tags: quill, superscript

```
  if (!worksheet) {
    var data = [{ 'Value': value, 'Solution': value1, 'Editorvalue':  editorvalue.innerHTML}];
  worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
  } else {
    var data = [{ 'Value': value, 'Solution': value1 }];
  var rowIndex = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(worksheet, data, { header: ['Value', 'Solution', 'Editorval'], skipHeader: true, origin: -1 });
  }
  console.log("appended")
  })
```

I have this code but when the quill editor content contains superscript and subscript or anyother values it displays as HTML tags in excel But i want to display as it is? How to do that?

I want to store the quill content as it is even it contains superscript or subscript.